# Partial view issue - jQuery not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am facing jQuery loading issue in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I am trying to load a partial view so I have used

> @Html.Action("GetView", "Home")

Partial view contains some jQuery functions. When it's loaded it shows jQuery not defined message, but jQuery is working on main page.

So I have tried two other methods to load the partial view and there is no issue of jQuery with these methods

```
@Html.Partial("_viewname")

@Ajax.BeginForm()
```

**Home Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetView(string id = "")
        {
           return PartialView("_ViewName");

        }
    }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("Head", false)
</head>
<body>
    <section >
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div>
            @RenderSection("Sidebar", false)
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
```

**Parent Page Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
}

<div id="main_content">
    @Html.Action("GetView", "Packages")
</div>
```

**Partial View _view.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").addClass("form-control");
    });

</script>
```

I think there is some jQuery loading issue, but I don't understand why this is happening on specific action.

Please suggest me solution for this issue.

Comment: Where is the page that contains the rendering of the partial view?

Comment: can you the partial view and the parent view code?

Comment: Include the scripts from your partial

Comment: plus check whether the jquery is being loaded using firebug

Comment: Your jQuery is being rendered at the end of the body, make sure all the scripts in your partial view are inside your Scripts-section or else jQuery is not loaded yet when you try to use it.

Answer (score 18):

Your views (not partial views) need to include the code in a `@section Scripts` block. As you pointed out `@section`s do not work in Partial Views.

Ensure your code in the parent view is in one like this:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
         // DOM ready handler if needed
         $(function(){
              // Your Javascript/jQuery code here
         });
    </script>
}
```

The `@section` directive tells the view builder where to insert this block in the master page. With Javascript you need it to always be in the Scripts section, or it will be rendered inline where it was declared.

The alternative is to move the jQuery inclusion to before `RenderBody()` calls in the master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("Head", false)
    <!-- jQuery -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    <section >
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

        <div>
            @RenderSection("Sidebar", false)
        </div>

    </section>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
```

The browser caching associated with using bundles means only the very first page load will be a tiny bit inefficient on your site.

Comment: Yeah, i am also thinking to use JS in head but i am trying to find solution if available!

Comment: @AskQuestion: You are correct (forgot about that). Have updated answer. You need to move your code to the view contained the partial rendering or move the jQuery up (both options are outlined).

Comment: I am trying to improve page load performance that's why i am using JS in bottom of page

Comment: Bundling (and the associated browser caching) alone will improve performance beyond what placing jQuery at the end will do, but the other option is to put the code in your views.

Comment: This solution will not work if there the partial view contains dynamic script to do things like loading d3.js charts that requires the script run on the partial view. Any advice for this situation?

Comment: @spadelives: In our projects we felt that partial views loading their own scripts was a bad idea, so instead an event is triggered when panels were loaded and plugins were reapplied to elements in loaded panels with a specific class (e.g. AddInD3 etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you must run scripts on a partial view, as is the case when dynamically created content is returned when calling partial views from an AJAX call, you should find that the problem described in the question actually only happens on the initial parent page load. If this is the case, you can work around the problem by **NOT** loading the partial on the primary view. Instead, you can load the partial view using JQuery **AFTER** the initial page load.

So, instead of doing this inline with the HTML on the primary view:

```
@Html.Partial("YourCoolDynamicDashboard")
```

Do this in a .js file or within your primary view's javascript tag:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.get("/YourController/YourCoolDynamicDashboard", [<... data goes here...>], function (result) {
            $("#YourDashboardContainer").html(result);    
      });
});
```

This work around will allow you to run client-side JQuery code on both the primary view AND in the partial view.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   //Define Jquery here
});
```

This worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).